# Linear order embeddable in reals and the power set of naturals

Tags: set-theory

I'm asked to prove that for $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$ linear order $$ \langle X,\preceq\rangle \ \text{embeddable in}\ \langle P(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq\rangle \iff \langle X,\preceq\rangle \ \text{embeddable in}\ \langle \mathbb{R},\leq\rangle.$$
Nonetheless I find it quite confusing, as to my mind if the LHS is true, the embedding gives us a well ordered subset of $P(\mathbb{N})$ (as the order by inclusion has the least element, namely the empty set), say $A$.

So we can construct and incjection $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$  letting $f(S)=|S|,\  S\in A$. So $|A|\leq |\mathbb{N}|$ and this in turn would imply $|X|\leq |\mathbb{N}|$.

But if the RHS is true, it does not necessarily follow that $|X|\leq |\mathbb{N}|$, for instance by letting $X=\mathbb{R}$ with natural order (an identity embedding).

Am I making any mistake?

Comment: ${\mathbb R}$ with its usual order embeds in the partial order on the left: You can replace ${\mathcal P}({\mathbb N})$ with ${\mathcal P}({\mathbb Q})$ (right?). Now identify $r\in{\mathbb R}$ with its Dedekind cut (that is, with the set of rationals to the left of $r$).

Comment: Your confusion suggests that you are making at least two mistakes. One  is ignoring a quantifier in the definition of well-order: For a set to be well-ordered, It is not enough that the set itself has a least element, but also *every* (non-empty) subset of it must have a least element. As the example above shows, this may fail dramatically in this case.

Comment: The second mistake is a bit more difficult to decipher, but it seems that you are thinking of embeddings as having range "an initial segment". This is not true. Even if the set $X$ you are embedding is well-ordered, you do nit need to map its first element to the empty set.

Comment: **HINT:** It suffices to prove that any linear suborder of $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N), \subseteq)$ can be embedded into $(\mathbb R, \le)$.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that: 1. $S \mapsto |S|$ is well defined (what about infinite sets?), 2. it is an injective map (there could be different sets with the same cardinality). These two fact are obviously false, so that your map $f$ does not give you $|X| \le |\Bbb{N}|$.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, you're right guys. I'm gonna ponder it a little bit more.